# CMake "--target install" without "--build" command line

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

It might be a silly question for some of you, but is it possible to call cmake `--target install` command option without having to specify `--build` when using VS generator?

I'm working on a library project that sometimes I don't want to always specify build, i.e:

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

I guess cmake forces us to do it in this order to avoid errors, but what if my project is already built and I don't want cmake to re-check my project build and just install? Like we can do with `jom install` or `nmake install` etc..
 this won't work:

```
cmake --target install
```

or

```
cmake . --target install
```

Thanks in advance for the answers! :)

Answer (score 4):

For cmake, version >= 3.15, you now have the `--install` flag doing exactly what you need.
The flag is required to be the first, see the relevant [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project).
It works like a charm on UNIX and Windows (also with VS generator).
In your case, it would be:

```
cmake --install .
```

*Note:* I experienced one (probable) backward compatibility problem which I didn't investigate further when building and installing VTK-7.1.1 on windows: the plugins were not handled correctly.
I don't know if it's specific to VTK's cmake implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency of the install target on the "Build All" target is controlled by the setting of the cmake variable [CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY.html).

If you are using a Makefile based generator, CMake also generates a special install target "install/fast" which does not build before installing. It can be invoked in the following way:

```
cmake --build . --target install/fast
```

Comment: That's interesting! Thanks for the info. But unfortunately that's not my case. I use on windows VS generator and it generates only INSTALL.vcxproj and I didn't find any fast.vcxproj.